# How to find page count of PDF file in java without using external library?

Tags: java

How can I find total number of pages of a PDF file, without using any external library in java ?

Comment: PDF is not a format which `java` understands, you will need a library

Comment: Java can perfectly well read PDF files, but it is a binary file and quite comples. Start with reviewing the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) and implement the ISO 32000-1. standard. A library is "only" a program part someone else already made for you, and there are java libraries for reading PDF, so java, as any somewhat complete programming language, can understand the format.

Comment: Poor choice of wording, you could potentially look for page breaks in the byte array, but rather use a library

Comment: If he asks how he can do it without using an external library, why would he go for an external library? Maybe he can't for reasons. Anthon put it right, after all, those libraries to deal with PDFs also do it without using an external library... You can discuss "external library" vs "self-coding" of course and "external library" will win in most situations, but it doesn't change the question. Sorry for the rant, I'm just opposed to comments like those.

As for the question: look how the PDF format works (see Anthon's comment) and use input streams. There won't be an easier way not using libs.